# Android : Help in RadioButton Toast

Tags: android, radio-button, toast

[image]

If user clicks NEXT button without selecting option it has to toast a message, "pls select any one" else it should goto  next screen.  I have tried but its not going to next screen, Instead its showing  toast"pls select any one"  and my code

```
public class Question1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button vid, next;
Typeface tp;
TextView tv;
RadioGroup rg;
RadioButton rb;
Button b;
SharedPreferences sp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.question1);
    sp = getSharedPreferences("AppFile1", 0);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvQuestion1);

    rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    vid = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonQuestion1VIdeo);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonQuestion1Next);
    vid.setOnClickListener(this);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.buttonQuestion1VIdeo:
        Intent i = new Intent(Question1.this, VideoActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    case R.id.buttonQuestion1Next:
        if (next.isSelected()) {
            int selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            String s = rb.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
            ed.putString("q1", s);
            ed.commit();
            Intent ia = new Intent(Question1.this, Question2.class);
            startActivity(ia);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Select Answer", 0).show();
        }

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: debug it and Apply break point and get the Values and compare the Results 1st

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()!=-1) {
        int selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
        String s = rb.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
        ed.putString("q1", s);
        ed.commit();
        Intent ia = new Intent(Question1.this, Question2.class);
        startActivity(ia);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Select Answer", 0).show();
    }
```

The documentation says that if no button is checked, [getCheckedRadioButtonId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#getCheckedRadioButtonId%28%29) returns `-1`.

> Returns the identifier of the selected radio button in this group. Upon empty selection, the returned value is -1.

Therefore, if you have any value except -1 from that function, you have a selected button.

Answer (score 3):

**wrong condition**: `if (next.isSelected())`

**True condition:** As you want to make sure option must be select:

```
boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are checking the selection state of Next button itself in condition.
But you want to check radio button selection state.
So you have to give it as:

```
if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()!=-1) {
            int selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            String s = rb.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
            ed.putString("q1", s);
            ed.commit();
            Intent ia = new Intent(Question1.this, Question2.class);
            startActivity(ia);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Select Answer", 0).show();
        }
```

Comment: means it's not possible to check  any option selected or not inside `RadioGroup` without check all radiobutton

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK No, it's possible, too. :) My mistake . Editing

Answer (score 0):

the condition will be like this

```
rb1  = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb1);
rb2  = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb2);
rb3  = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb3);

if(rb1.isChecked()==false && rb2.isChecked()==false && rb3.isChecked()==false)
{
     // Toast message is here
}
else
{
    // Intent code is here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RadioGroup rad_grp;
Button clear,submit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

clear = findViewById(R.id.clear);
submit = findViewById(R.id.submit);
rad_grp = findViewById(R.id.rad_grp);
rad_grp.clearCheck();


rad_grp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        RadioButton rb = group.findViewById(checkedId);
        if (null != rb && checkedId > -1)
        {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }
});

clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        rad_grp.clearCheck();
    }
});

submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        RadioButton rb = rad_grp.findViewById(rad_grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+rb.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rad_grp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/male"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Male"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/female"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Female"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/other"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Other"/>


</RadioGroup>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your answer is just code. Please add some explanation to your code to be useful.