# How can I save radio buttons states on Android?

Tags: android

I want to save the states of `RadioButton` using Shared Preference so on submit button I can get all changes values..

I want to save all the states of `RadioButton` and on-click for prev and next buttons it must save the state.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586837/android-save-state-of-radio-buttons

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946800/android-help-in-radiobutton-toast/13946832#13946832

Comment: See [Shared Preferences | Android Developer Tutorial](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html) for storing and getting data from sharedpreferences

Comment: I am displaying data from hash map and on click of radio button , what should i do means how should i save values so on submit button i must do other scoring perform...

Please tell me how to do see my problem is 

i have questions and 3 options radio button to choose and 

Next button and prev button so 

ON next button next values will be fetched and on prev button I must be able to see the save state and also,

and these changed values i will be storing in new table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store your information in SharedPreferences like this.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Answers", 0); 
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("questionA", radBotA.isChecked()); 
  editor.putBoolean("questionB", radBotB.isChecked());
  editor.putBoolean("questionC", radBotC.isChecked());
  editor.putBoolean("questionD", radBotD.isChecked());
  editor.commit();
```

when coming back to the activity call this `onStart()`

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Answers", 0);
  radBotA.setChecked(settings.getBoolean("questionA", false)); 
  radBotB.setChecked(settings.getBoolean("questionB", false));
  radBotC.setChecked(settings.getBoolean("questionC", false));
  radBotD.setChecked(settings.getBoolean("questionD", false));
```

Comment: Thanks Bill Gates, How i will load on next and prev button, please tell :)) , now 

I just want that on next button click i will press some option and on previous button when i clicked is it will show the radio button as i selected

Comment: by next button are you going to some other activity??

Comment: No i am calling hash map so it will pass id value and object and it will set the questions and options to screen

Comment: I am calling nextQues(object, i) so this is through hash map all values will be comming.. from hash map bean and id

Comment: can you pls add your code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/08B5B400 check this

Comment: How should i save on prev and next means and on update it should also save the state of radio button again in shared pref

Comment: so are you saving the answer in a database when the next button is pressed?

Comment: its better to use a database in this case as there are lots of question and anwers.

Comment: when user will click the finish button i will save all those values to database